# Cannot setting the state with the data fetched in useEffect -React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, use-effect

I want to send an API request in useEffect hook and setting the state variables value with the fetched data. I added 2 console.log for detecting the state variables value. I except the second log to be setted with the fetched data, however it still prints null.

Here is my code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
const Test = () =>{
    const [users, setUsers] = useState(null);
    useEffect(()=>{
        const getData = async ()=>{
            const resp = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos");
            console.log(users);
            setUsers(resp.data);
            console.log(users);
        };
        getData();
    },[])
    return (
        <div>hello</div>
    )
};

export default Test;
```

Additionally the console output look likes this:

```
null
null
```

Comment: State changes are asynchronous, you can't print them on the next line of code and see the change. Print state in the main body of the function to get the latest values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useState`'s setter is asynchronous, therefore your second `console.log` will be called before the `users` is actually updated.

For it to work, just put it outside the `useEffect`.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
const Test = () =>{
    const [users, setUsers] = useState(null);
    useEffect(()=>{
        const getData = async ()=>{
            const resp = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos");
            console.log(users);
            setUsers(resp.data);
        };
        getData();
    },[])
    console.log(users);
    return (
        <div>hello</div>
    )
};

export default Test;
```

or in another dedicated `useEffect`, by passing `users` in the dependencies array.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
const Test = () =>{
    const [users, setUsers] = useState(null);
    useEffect(()=>{
        const getData = async ()=>{
            const resp = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos");
            console.log(users);
            setUsers(resp.data);
        };
        getData();
    },[])

    useEffect(()=>{
       console.log(users);
    },[users])

    return (
        <div>hello</div>
    )
};
```